# Testing MUI popver with jest and react-testing-library - jest-preview showing different results in debug?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I have a popover that displays some content fetched from an api. In the tests, i use MSW to handle mocking out the api end point, and the data is returned to the component correctly. Here's the component:

```
const MapContainer = (props: MapContainerProps) => {
return <Popover
            id={id}
            open={open}
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            onClose={handleClose}
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
            }}
        >
            <Box sx={{maxHeight: '80vh'}} data-testid={'map-actions-params-popover-content'}>
                <pre style={{
                    backgroundColor: grey[100],
                    padding: '8px'
                }}>{JSON.stringify(result.detail, null, 2)}</pre>
            </Box>
        </Popover>
})
```

and here's the failing test

```
it('shows parameter file content (response.detail) in popover', async () => {

        render(<Router>
            <AppContextProvider>
                <MapContainer
                    url={ENDPOINTS.map_retrieve.replace(':id', '40')}
                    handleStatusChange={jest.fn()}/>
            </AppContextProvider></Router>)

        // wait for data to be fetched

        await waitFor(() => {
            user.click(screen.getByTestId('map-actions-params-button'))
        })
        

        await waitFor(() => {
            preview.debug();
            expect(screen.getByText('User Parameters').toBeInTheDocument())
        })
    })
```

When I use jest-preview to debug at the failing assertion, I can see the popover has the required content, but the test is persistently failing.

**Unable to find an element with the text: User Parameters. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.**

I've used findByText, getByText, various combinations of waitFor, using a function in the matcher:
`expect(screen.getByText((_, element) => element.textContent === 'User Parameters')).toBeInTheDocument()`
and still no luck. What am I doing wrong?